# cannot find symbol - constructor Car()

Tags: java

I'm trying to use a method from another class called Car but referring to it in a class called Bike. I've tried to create an instance variable by using the following code

```
Car b = new Car();
b.higherLease
```

It just keeps coming up with error: cannot find symbol - constructor Car() The car class works perfectly though. ANy help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is it maybe a private instead of a public class? In any case, post the code of class Car.

Comment: Maybe you can post some code?

Comment: Agree that there's not nearly enough information to answer this question. For all we know, there is no default Car constructor and all the constructors take a parameter. Please don't make us guess -- show the code.

Answer (score 2):

make sure the class is public (or protected if in the same package).
you can check to see if it recognise the Car class by defining a static method foo
and then calling Car.foo(); from Bike.

Comment: the car class is public though. It does recognize the non static object being referred to by a static one.

Comment: Then just post some code......

Comment: also try using the auto fix (maybe you haven't imorted the Car class). if you use sophisticated enviorment it might be very easy to solve. what is your work enviorment? i recommend eclipse (www.eclipse.org) which is free.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have imported the `class` Car. You can import by adding this line after the `package` statement.

```
import yourclass; // fully qualified class name.
```

But you need to get ide like [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) or something which does it automatically.

Comment: Again, DON'T do that.  Instead, as has been requested many many times in this thread, post your flippin' code. We need to see if all your Car constructors take parameters. If so, you're calling the constructor wrong.